# How to find average of two tables in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have one table with 1000s of rows that looks like this: 
file1:

```
apples1 + hate 0 0 0 2 4 6 0 1 
apples2 + hate 0 2 0 4 4 6 0 2 
apples4 + hate 0 2 0 4 4 6 0 2
```

and another file with same headers in file2 - nb some headers are missing in file1:

```
apples1 + hate 0 0 0 1 4 6 0 2 
apples2 + hate 0 1 0 6 4 6 0 2
apples3 + hate 0 2 0 4 4 6 0 2 
apples4 + hate 0 1 0 3 4 3 0 1
```

I want to compare the two files in pandas and average across common columns. I do not want to print columns that are in one file only. So the resultant file would look like:

```
apples1 + hate 0 0 0 1.5 4 6 0 1.5 
apples2 + hate 0 1.5 0 5 4 6 0 2 
apples4 + hate 0 2 0 3.5 4 6 0 2
```

Comment: Just groupby and mean

Comment: Inner join of the two file on the first column, remove columns that contain NaN then as @Wen suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps in this solution.

1. concatenate all your dataframes by stacking them vertically (axis=0, the default) using `pandas.concat(...)` and specifying a join of 'inner' to only maintain columns that in all the dataframes.
2. call `mean(...)` function on resultant dataframe.

Example:

```
In [1]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], columns=['a','b','c'])
In [2]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=['a','c'])
In [3]: df1
Out[3]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

In [4]: df2
Out[4]:
   a  c
0  1  2
1  3  4

In [5]: df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], join='inner')
In [6]: df3
Out[6]:
   a  c
0  1  3
1  4  6
0  1  2
1  3  4

In [7]: df3.mean()
Out[7]:
a    2.25
c    3.75
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1', header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2', header=None)
```

Set index to first three columns ie.. "apple1 + hate"

```
df1 = df1.set_index([0,1,2])
df2 = df2.set_index([0,1,2])
```

Let's use `merge` to inner join datafiles on indexes, and the groupby columns with the same name and aggregate with `mean`:

```
df1.merge(df2, right_index=True, left_index=True)\
   .pipe(lambda x: x.groupby(x.columns.str.extract('(\w+)\_[xy]', expand=False),
                             axis=1, sort=False).mean()).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
         0  1     2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
0  apples1  +  hate  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.5  4.0  6.0  0.0  1.5
1  apples2  +  hate  0.0  1.5  0.0  5.0  4.0  6.0  0.0  2.0
2  apples4  +  hate  0.0  1.5  0.0  3.5  4.0  4.5  0.0  1.5
```